# Google Sheet countif only visible data using sumtotal

Tags: google-sheets, sum, counting, countif, subtotal

```
Sell / Buy
Buy
Buy
Sell
```

Hi all,
I have google sheet that has a lot of Data However, i want to count number of "Buy" and "Sell" based on filtering the dates NOT the whole column  ONLY VISIBLE rows

[image]

The code i'm trying to use is the below

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(E4,ROW(E4:E100)-ROW(E4),,1)),--(E4:E100 = "Buy"))
```

i'm really having bad time solving this issue, i would greatly appreciate if someone can help me with the code.

thank you.

Comment: You no need to filer. Use Countifs() formula.

Comment: please not i only want to use formula not anything else like conditional formating or anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add column of `SUBTOTAL`

```
=SUBTOTAL(103, B4)
```

[image]

hide it:

[image]

then use:

```
=COUNTA(IFNA(FILTER(B4:B, C4:C="buy", D4:D=1)))
```

[image]

```
=COUNTIF(D4:D, 1)
```

[image]

```
="Buy: "&  COUNTIFS(C4:C, "buy",  D4:D, 1)&
 " Sell: "&COUNTIFS(C4:C, "sell", D4:D, 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help, But can this be done without a new helper column ??

Comment: Cool! I see at https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093649 that `103` means `COUNTA` with hidden values skipped.